# Gem load error when trying to use RinRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r

I am trying to use the RinRuby gem, but when trying to fire up my rails server I get the following error:

```
 in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'rinruby'. 

(Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: No such file or directory - R
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/Users/reinierverbeek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rinruby-2.0.3/lib/rinruby.rb:164:in `popen'
/Users/reinierverbeek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rinruby-2.0.3/lib/rinruby.rb:164:in `initialize'
/Users/reinierverbeek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rinruby-2.0.3/lib/rinruby.rb:789:in `new'
```

I have R installed and my .bash-profile file looks like this:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}”
export PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export R_HOME="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
source ~/.profile
```

I added this bash file, because I also noticed that I am not able to execute R scripts from the CLI using Rscript, but I have to include the whole path

```
"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/Rscript"
```

I also tried to edit my path with the following:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/Rscript”
```

but this didn't help